# Need advice on ansible-pull and vault

Tags: ansible, git, ansible-playbook, vault

Hope you're doing well.

I have this design headache

My very basic interrogation here is: how can i implement `ansible-pull` a "secure" way with kiss principle ?

For example i use `ansible-pull` to manage workstations :

At some point i'll need to transmit vaulted stuff to clients first being `become_password`.

To give you a little more context have this `local.yml` :

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  vars_files:
    - vars/all_vars.yml
  pre_tasks:
    # task for testing purposes only
    - name: 'Timedate needs to be ok for apt'
      raw: sudo systemctl restart chronyd && chronyc -a makestep
      tags:
        - always
    
    # end of testing purposes    
        
    - name: 'Installation tasks first and only one time'
      include_tasks:
        file: "{{ outer_item }}"
        apply:
          tags:
            - installation
      loop:
      - tasks/schedule.yml
      - tasks/packages.yml
      - tasks/upgrade_all.yml
      - tasks/users.yml
      - tasks/grub.yml
      loop_control:
        loop_var: outer_item
      tags:
        - installation

    - name: 'Security tasks at each reboot'
      include_tasks:
        file: "{{ outer2_item }}"
        apply:
          tags:
            - security
      loop:
      - tasks/schedule.yml
      - tasks/security.yml

      loop_control:
        loop_var: outer2_item
      tags:
        - security

  environment:
    LANG: en_US.UTF-8
```

`all_vars.yml` containing some vars and at some point secrets.

As far as i can see i can :

- put vault_pass in clear text on clients ?
- keeping secrets in clear in git repo ( not a good practice at all )

Anyone could give me hint on this please ?

Thank you ;) have a good day.